# C/C++ Netbeans LInux --- Build Host not Connected

Tags: compiling, c++, netbeans

I'm wondering if the following error has anything to do with the error of 'Build Host not Connected' when attempting to create a C++ project -- >

---

Warning - could not install some modules: com.jcraft.jsch - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /home/victor/.netbeans/10.0/modules/com-jcraft-jsch.jar: Cannot start com.jcraft.jsch state remains INSTALLED after start()

---

Context on my machine:
- Ubuntu 18.04
- Netbeans 10.0

Context on error:
- I had just downloaded the C/C++ Plugin and it had given me an error saying "Could not install some modules: com.jcraft.jsch - org.netbeans.InvalidException:Netigso"

I have also downloaded MingW as a compiler but the thing is, I downloaded it after downloading C/C++ Plugin, is there a pathing problem ? When I look under "Build Host" there is also no options listed under.

Sorry, I am completely clueless on where the problem may lay and this is my first question, please be lenient

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Wait for Netbeans 11.2 or may be later... https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NETBEANS/Apache+NetBeans+11.2

Netbeans has not c++ support after moving to Apache Foundation.

Answer (score 0):

it worked for me using only NetBeans version 11!!! it failed with 11.3!!!
I had also to enable nb8.2 plugin portal to get C/C++ !!! if you need more help say it. It is working here and I can give more details if it helps!!!